# Ingredients: Danish local specials

Tags: regional-cuisine

I'm visiting Denmark. I'd like to bring home some local Danish ingredients so I can prepare a meal from Danish cuisine. (It can be Scandinavian, if Danish is too narrow.)
It doesn't necessarily have to be a full-blown meal, it can be a snack or something equally simple.

Additional requirement: It should survive flight, so I'm thinking more about either something dry, or canned, or similar.

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Bfore you attempt this, you should check what the import laws are in your country of origin.  I've had cat food confiscated when re-entering the US ... because it's made with meat (I was transporting two cats, and had bags of food taped to the cages so I could feed them; they didn't attempt to take the food that was in the bowls in with the cats, though).  No meat or fresh produce can come in, although I have declared spices before and they were okay with it.  (which was good, as it was a couple ounces of saffron)

Comment: @Joe - Poland and Denmark are part of the EU, it's 800 km ish from Denmark via Germany. It's a bit like driving from Maryland to Michigan, no real borders to worry about

Comment: @TFD : I wasn't sure ... but if someone else were to read this question, and think the same response applied, they could be quite annoyed if they come home only to have their items confiscated.  Hell, I even had a time when I changed planes in Madrid (from international to domestic within Spain), and they made me go back through security, meaning I had to give up items bought at the duty-free shop as they were liquids and I only had my carry-on.

Comment: Liquids on aeroplanes are a different issue - that's something to check before you board. Last time I went through Spanish airspace I was allowed to carry two bottles on board because the seals were intact. My wife had to throw her cola away, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm from Denmark but I've lived in so many other places. Here's a list of things that usually go well:

- *leverpostej*, similar to foie gras, tastes very good on rye bread.
- *marineret sild*, marinated herring, also very good on rye bread.
- *flæskesvær*, crunchy salty pig skin :-) people say it tastes a lot better than it sounds, and though I personally disagree, my foreign colleagues like it.
- "proper" (strong) liquorice like Haribo's *Super Piratos* or Leaf's *Lakrisal* - because anything with less than 6% ammonium chloride is for wusses!
- various kinds of cheese and bread, as has been said already.
- *wienerbrød*, Danish pastry, especially *kringle* and *spandauer* are delicious.
- *makrel i tomat*, canned mackerel (fish) in tomato juice, yet another delicious treat on rye bread.

Comment: +1 Wouldn't it be easier just to get rye bread and potatoes :-)

Comment: Are flæskesvær similar to the UK pork scratchings, or US pork rinds?

Comment: @klypos Yes I think those are comparable but I don't know them.

Comment: Huge thanks for the answer. I can hardly express how good it was. Danish names helped with shopping. And despite we have similar things in Poland, where I live, these things come in different flavors, e.g. I haven't eaten herrings marinated the ways Danish folk use. All in all, great answer.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. Smacznego!

Answer (score 2):

The Danish do a nice line in pickled cucumbers, cheeses and crispbreads. Cheeses to look at include Havarti, Samsoe, Esrom, Maribo and the various kinds of Danish Blue. The pickled cucumbers are very much a local thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of breads you could get - a lot of sourdough, rye and seed breads. Open sandwiches are popular in Denmark, for some reason. Also Danish salami can be very good.

Answer (score 0):

Licorice (danish: lakrids). But, er, buy a bag first and see if you enjoy the local interpretation or not.